# where can I find a valid JSON link that I can use to test my applications?

Tags: json

I tried this one which I found here -

http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json

But if I test its validity, it gives me an error.

I validated it here:

http://jsonlint.com/

Can anyone point me to a functional JSON link that I can use to test my applications?

Comment: Why don't you create your own ? Btw tumblr's json is valid, you just need to request it using the jsonp protocol

Comment: How about the json for this question? https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/17864031?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a 'My IP' type service that returns JSON.

http://whoami.bradallen.net/

Answer (score 1):

Why not try out the free [stackexchange api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)?

```
burhan@lenux:~$ http "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/1755023?site=stackoverflow"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: private
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 433
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 16:54:31 GMT

{
    "has_more": false, 
    "items": [
        {
            "accept_rate": 91, 
            "account_id": 1950909, 
            "age": 27, 
            "badge_counts": {
                "bronze": 9, 
                "gold": 0, 
                "silver": 0
            }, 
            "creation_date": 1350528803, 
            "display_name": "Rj.", 
            "is_employee": false, 
            "last_access_date": 1374770664, 
            "last_modified_date": 1372353815, 
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1755023/rj", 
            "location": "West Hollywood, CA", 
            "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f1f3ab1c31c6ee987ba28a78318586fd?d=identicon&r=PG", 
            "reputation": 423, 
            "reputation_change_day": 5, 
            "reputation_change_month": 95, 
            "reputation_change_quarter": 95, 
            "reputation_change_week": 5, 
            "reputation_change_year": 315, 
            "user_id": 1755023, 
            "user_type": "registered", 
            "website_url": ""
        }
    ], 
    "quota_max": 300, 
    "quota_remaining": 294
}
```